# Designing for text heavy content.

Tags: website-design, user-experience

I'm a junior UI/UX designer and I'm struggling to design websites in our company because the content team is tasked to do 200-300 word sections in the home page.

The content will look like this..
-200 words per section with one h1, and h2 each.. maximum of 3 sections, I'm kind of confused because what I learned in seminars, online courses is that home pages should generally tell a story and not be heavy with content.

Do you guys have a workaround for this? sorry if I'm not clear, not a native English speaker.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. I suggest this was the reason that Ward Cunningham, creator of the World Wide Web, created hypertext links in order that detail can be placed/linked-to on a second level to be available when wanted/needed. Did you know there's a https://ux.stackexchange.com where User eXperience is discussed? They might have something of interest.

Comment: "I learned in seminars, online courses" And now you will add online forums... Go and make decisions. Each project is a new case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the story you want to tell and who your audience is. 200 words is not really all that much IF you have something to say. Problem with most webpages is that they have nothing to contribute*. So if you have something to say your fine.

* If you have nothing to say saying it in 200-300 words will just cause me to jump ship.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on the type of workaround you are asking about but some options:

- If you feel the copy is long-winded and repetitive (or boring), you
  can have a conversation with the client to see if there is the
  possibility of hiring an editor that would help you both reach your
  goals.
- In terms of visual, consider different weights. Using a condensed
  font will help make your text seem much shorter (though make sure
  it's still comfortably legible).